# HQL some tables are joined some are not - please explain

Tags: hql

I have come across some hql that looks like this:

```
select a.id
from something a inner join a.whatever b,
     somethingelse c inner join c.blah d
where a.id = c.id
```

Why is a inner joined to b and c inner joined to d but a is linked to c via where

What exactly is this hql saying? Please explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query means that the a and b are related in the model. Same is the case with c and d.
In order to join a and c, you have to explicitly state the join field, i.e., id since the model does not have this information.